# How should the excluded middle be used in the proof of the pigeonhole principle?

Tags: coq

```
Lemma remove {A} (x : A) xs (p : In x xs) :
  exists xs', (forall x', x' <> x -> In x' xs -> In x' xs') /\ (length xs = S (length xs')).
Proof.
induction xs.
- inversion p.
- destruct p.
  + subst x0.
    exists xs.
    split.
    * intros x' neq pin.
      destruct pin.
      -- contradict neq. symmetry. assumption.
      -- assumption.
    * reflexivity.
  + destruct (IHxs H) as [xs' pxs']. clear IHxs.
    destruct pxs' as [p1 plen]. rename x0 into x'.
    exists (x' :: xs').
    split.
    * intros x'' neq pin. 
      destruct pin.
      -- subst x'. left. reflexivity.
      -- right. apply p1. assumption. assumption.
    * simpl.
      rewrite -> plen.
      reflexivity. 
Qed.

Theorem pigeonhole_principle: forall (X:Type) (l1  l2:list X),
  excluded_middle ->
  AllIn l1 l2 ->
  length l2 < length l1 ->
  repeats l1.
Proof.
induction l1; simpl; intros l2 ex_mid Hin Hlen.
- inversion Hlen.
- apply repeats_rest.
  destruct (remove x l2) as [l2' Hl2].
  + apply Hin. left. reflexivity.
  + destruct Hl2 as [Hmap Hlen'].
    rewrite Hlen' in Hlen.
    clear Hlen'.
    apply (IHl1 l2').
    1 : { assumption. }
    2 : { revert Hlen. unfold lt. intros. omega. }
    clear Hlen IHl1.
    revert Hin.
    unfold AllIn.
    intros.
    apply Hmap.
    2 : { apply Hin. right. assumption. }
```

```
1 subgoal
X : Type
x : X
l1, l2 : list X
ex_mid : excluded_middle
l2' : list X
Hmap : forall x' : X, x' <> x -> In x' l2 -> In x' l2'
Hin : forall u : X, In u (x :: l1) -> In u l2
u : X
H : In u l1
______________________________________(1/1)
u <> x
```

I found various solutions floating about for the pigeonhole principle on the net. The above is adapted from the one by [Kovacs](https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/071ea86702732dc25ba6), but in his proof he proves that there is an absence of no duplicates rather that there are repetitions as in the SF exercise.

The marked difference is that I cannot prove the `u <> x` goal here because there is less information when the problem is stated in this form.

Since this problem is both hard and optional and there are existing solutions floating around - and I've already been working on it for two days, could somebody describe to me a high level plan of exactly what I need to make this proof.

I am not looking for a solution, but I am hoping that the one with the excluded middle turns out to be elegant, because the Coq proof [without the excluded middle](https://github.com/llbit/Pigeonhole-Principle) is just a mess of rewriting and knowing the source code of a program is far from understanding what it does. Most explanations of the principle just describe what it is which is not enough for me to bridge the intuition gap.

I've never seen the classical laws in action - it does not seem like knowing something is decidable would gain me much and I find it hard to see what the point of them is. This is especially so in this situation, so I am that much more interested to see what their purpose will turn out to be.

Comment: IIRC you don't need EM. Cf. [this solution in Agda](https://github.com/gallais/potpourri/blob/master/agda/poc/PigeonHole.agda) for a similar formulation using `repeats`.

Comment: Indeed, it is not needed, but the definition is much more simpler when it is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this question when searching for answers while working through SF (Software Foundations), but managed to prove it myself. I'll provide a sketch for the SF version of the pigeonhole principle, using excluded_middle. The statement to prove is that if all elements in list `l1` are in `l2` and `length l2` is less than `length l1`, then `l1` contains repeated elements.

The proof as SF suggests begins by induction on `l1`. I'll omit the straightforward empty case. In the inductive case, destruct `l2`. The case where `l2` is empty is straightforward; we consider the other case.

Now, because of induction on `l1` and destructuring on `l2`, your statement to prove is about lists with a first member, let's call them `x1::l1` and `x2::l2`. Your membership hypothesis now looks like: all elements in `x1::l1` are in `x2::l2`.

But first, let us use excluded middle to state that either `x1` in `l1` or `x1` not in `l1`. If `x1` in `l1`, then trivially we can prove that `x1::l1` has repeats. So moving forward, we may assume that `x1` is not in `l1`.

It suffices to match the inductive case that there exists an `l2'` of the same length as `l2` such that all elements of `l1` are in `l2'`.

Now consider the membership hypothesis on `x1::l1`, with the forall variable introduced as `x`:

By hypothesis, we know that `x1` in `x2::l2`. Now consider `l2'`, where `l2'` is `x2::l2` with one instance of `x1` removed (use `in_split`). Now because `x1` not in `l1`, we can conclude that all members of `l1` are also in `l2'` and not the removed element. Then this satisfies the membership hypothesis in the induction, and some wrangling with lengths gives us `length l2 = S (length l2')`, so that the length hypothesis is satisfied. We thus conclude that `l1` contains repeats, and thus also `x1::l1`.

Edit: previously, I also did a case analysis on whether or not `x1` = `x2` or `x1` in `l2`, and whether or not `x` = `x2` or `x` in `l2`, and solved the special cases in a more straightforward manner. It's not needed, and the general case also covers them.

Edit: correct typo `length l2 = length l2`

Comment: I won't check whether your solution is formally correct, but will instead take your word for it. 5.5 months ago when I asked this, somehow the pigeonhole proof had the effect of completely dumbfounding me and I was completely lost as to what was going on. Eventually, with much effort and over a period of time I figured out the Agda proof and forgot the non-constructive version, but still it is good to have it somewhere.

Comment: You do not need such a case analysis. You know that `x1` is in `x2::l2`. You do not need to consider the cases `x1 = x2` and `x1` is in `l2` separately. You can use `in_split` directly with `x2::l2`.

Answer (score 1):

jhanschoo's answer is fantastically helpful and I think there is quite a bit of merit in trying to think through the answer before looking at someone else's code, so I didn't want to edit his answer, and to future readers please attempt to work through his answer first.

However, it took me a while to realize that I needed some extra theorems after the application of `in_split`, so I figured I would share my answer. (Of minor note: the hypotheses appear to be swapped in newer versions of Software Foundations.) I tried to make my solution as clear as possible when stepping through it.

```
Theorem leSBoth : forall n m, S n <= S m <-> n <= m.
(* a theorem I wrote which was useful throughout the IndProp chapter *)
Proof.
  split.
  - intros. inversion H. apply le_n.
    rewrite <- plus_1_l in H1. apply plus_le, proj2 in H1. apply H1.
  - intros. induction H. apply le_n. apply le_S. apply IHle.
Qed.

Inductive repeats {X:Type} : list X -> Prop :=
  | repeats_x x xs : In x xs -> repeats (x::xs)
  | repeats_xs x xs : repeats xs -> repeats (x::xs).

Theorem pigeonhole_principle: excluded_middle ->
  forall (X:Type) (l1  l2:list X),
  (forall x, In x l1 -> In x l2) ->
  length l2 < length l1 ->
  repeats l1.
Proof.
  intros EM X l1. induction l1 as [|x l1' IHl1'].
  - (* l1 = [] *)
    simpl. intros. inversion H0.
  - (* l1 = x :: l1' *)
    simpl. intros l2 HIn Hlen. destruct l2 as [|y l2'].
    + (* l2 = [] *)
      intros. simpl in Hlen. exfalso. apply (HIn x). left. reflexivity.
    + (* l2 = y :: l2' *)
      destruct (EM (In x l1')) as [EmInT | EmInF].
      * (* In x l1' *)
        apply repeats_x. apply EmInT.
      * (* ~ In x l1' *) 
        destruct (in_split _ x (y::l2')) as [la [lb Eyl2]].
        -- (* must prove [In x (y :: l2')] to get equation below *) 
           apply (HIn x). left. reflexivity.
        -- (* Eyl2: y :: l2' = la ++ x :: lb *)
           apply repeats_xs. apply (IHl1' (la++lb)).
           ++ (* must prove [In x l1' -> In x l2] where [l2 = la ++ lb] *)
              intros z HInz. rewrite Eyl2 in HIn.
              (* assertion is important below *)
              assert (Neqx : x <> z).
              { unfold not in HInz. unfold not. intros Exz. rewrite Exz in EmInF.
                apply EmInF. apply HInz. }
              (* need to show this implication when [x <> z] so we can apply later *)
              assert (In_split_Neqx: In z (la ++ x :: lb) -> In z (la ++ lb)).
              { intros In_unsplit. apply In_app_iff. apply In_app_iff in In_unsplit.
                destruct In_unsplit as [Iu | Iu].
                left. apply Iu. right. simpl in Iu. destruct Iu as [Eqx | In_lb].
                exfalso. apply Neqx, Eqx.
                apply In_lb. }
              apply In_split_Neqx. apply HIn. right. apply HInz.
           ++ (* must prove [length l2 < length l1'] where [l2 = la ++ lb] *)
              rewrite Eyl2 in Hlen.
              rewrite app_length in Hlen. simpl in Hlen. rewrite <- plus_n_Sm in Hlen.
              apply -> leSBoth in Hlen. unfold lt. rewrite app_length. apply Hlen.
Qed.
```